# how to select data from mysql using timestamp

Tags: php, mysql, date, timestamp

This query returns all the rows from my table, even where the end_timestamp is not defined:

```
SELECT * FROM table 
    WHERE UNIX_TIMESTAMP(end_time) >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP('1448914804') 
    AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP(end_time) <= UNIX_TIMESTAMP('1448914804')
```

This query works fine but I want to pass timestamp:

```
SELECT * FROM commercial 
    WHERE UNIX_TIMESTAMP(end_time) >= FROM_UNIXTIME('2015-11-30 20:14:00') 
    AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP(end_time) <= FROM_UNIXTIME('2015-11-30 20:14:05')
```

Comment: What type do you have for **end_time**?  Is it Date, DateTime, Timestamp or INT/LONG?

Comment: Would adding `AND end_time IS NOT NULL` to the first query fix it? Depends on the default value you set for the column.

Comment: Hi, end_time is a timestamp. I do have another column in the same table of type timestamp, can that be my problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mixing up two types here.

If you created *end_time* as an **INTEGER**/**LONG**, you could do this:

```
SELECT * FROM table 
    WHERE end_time >= 1448914804  
    AND   end_time <= 1448914804

SELECT * FROM table 
    WHERE end_time >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2015-11-30 20:14:00')
    AND   end_time <= UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2015-11-30 20:14:05')
```

or if it is a **DATETIME** or **TIMESTAMP**

```
SELECT * FROM table 
    WHERE end_time >= FROM_UNIXTIME( 1448914804 ) 
    AND   end_time <= FROM_UNIXTIME( 1448914804 )

SELECT * FROM table 
    WHERE end_time >= '2015-11-30 20:14:00' 
    AND   end_time <= '2015-11-30 20:14:05'
```

By the way, your first statement refers to table *table* and the second to *commercial*.

Comment: end_time is **TIMESTAMP** and I'd like too use `SELECT * FROM table 
    WHERE end_time >= FROM_UNIXTIME( 1448914804 ) 
    AND   end_time <= FROM_UNIXTIME( 1448914804 )` but for some reasons it returns nothing

Comment: Your answer is correct. My problem was that I was testing my queries against timestamp from different timezone. I used online converter that showed me timestamp from GMT instead of GMT+1